# Twilio `RequestValidator` throwing 'System.NullReferenceException'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, twilio, sms

I am using .NET 4.5 Web API as webhook for Twilio SMS reception. As Twilio recommended for security purposes, I am using the `RequestValidator` class of the Twilio library to validate the request before handling the SMS received.
The first step is to create an instance of the class before using it to validate the incoming request:

```cs
var requestValidator = new Twilio.Security.RequestValidator(authToken);
var isTwilio = requestValidator.Validate(requestUrl, parameters, signature);
```

The issue is happening on the first instruction, which is instantiating the `RequestValidator` class and throwing the following exception:

```
'requestValidator._hmac.Hash' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException'
```

[image: Screenshot of the exception]

**Despite the exception, the instance is created** but the validation operation (second instruction) keeps returning false. I am using the latest version of Twilio , and tried migrating the app to .NET 4.8, and made sure the TLS1.2 is enabled and adopted. The same code was working just fine a couple of weeks ago , and stopped working all of the sudden. I tried creating an instance of the `RequestValidator` class in a newly created .NET 5 console app and it's working fine , but throwing the `NullReferenceException` in apps that are targeting .NET 4.5 and 4.8.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce this issue, but no exceptions are thrown when I try it using .NET Framework 4.8.
Just as an experiment, could you try using a different development machine, if you are able to. I'm wondering if there's something up with your Windows or .NET installation since it used to work, but stopped working recently.

Comment: @Swimburger I created a console app for testing in a completely different environment and machine , but still the same error , using the latest version of Twilio nuget , and I tried both .Net 4.8 and 4.5 , same !

Comment: I wish I could reproduce the error. Feel free to share the console app to GitHub or something so I could clone it and try it. Other than that, maybe you can share the code for retrieving the `authToken`, `requestUrl`, `parameters`, and `signature` variables. Or maybe the full stacktrace.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up @Swimburger , please find in this  https://github.com/AmilkarDev/Twilio-RequestValidator-Issue  two sample projects , where test twilio is .Net5 and its RequestValidator does not throw any exceptions , while the testTwilio2 project with .Net4.8 has the RequestValidator class throwing the exception , to verify , just set a breakpoint on the line next to the instruction of creating RequestValidator instance , check the instance created , and you will find the exception.

Comment: Of course. Thank you for sharing! Unfortunately, I still didn't get the error with your samples from GitHub.